# Win API работа с конфигурационными файлами (.ini) из C#

Tags: c#, winapi, ini

Я создаю класс который будет работать с конфигурационными файлами из шарпа. Для чтения и записи следующую конструкуию:

```
#region File managers

private const int SIZE = 1024; //Максимальный размер (для чтения значения из файла)
    /// <summary>
    /// WinAPI - Извлекает строку из указанной секции инициализационного файла
    /// <param name="AppName">
    /// Имя секции содержащей имя ключа. Если параметр null то функция копирует все именя секций в подставленный буфер
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="KeyName">
    /// Имя ключа с которым ассоциируется извлекаемая строка. Если параметр null то все ключевые имяна в секции заданной как AppName копируются в буффер ReturnedString
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="Default"> 
    /// Строка по умолчанию. Если имя ключа не может быть найдено в инициализационном файле то функция копирует строку по умолчанию а буффер ReturnedString
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="ReturnedString">
    /// Указатель на буффер принимающий возвращаемую строку
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="Size">
    /// Размер буффера переданного по параметру ReturnedString.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="FileName">
    /// Имя инициализационного файла. Если параметр не содержит полного пути к файлу, 
    /// то система производит поиск файла в директории Windows
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// Количество скопированных символов не считая null-termonated символа
    /// </returns>
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private extern static int GetPrivateProfileString(String AppName, String KeyName, String Default, StringBuilder ReturnedString, UInt32 Size, String FileName);
    /// <summary>
    /// Удобная обертка для WinAPI функции GetPrivateProfileString
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="section">наименование секции</param>
    /// <param name="key">ключ</param>
    /// <returns>запрашиваемый параметр или null если ключь не был найден</returns>
    private string GetParam(string section, string key)
    {
        //Для получения значения
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(SIZE);

        //Получить значение в buffer
        GetPrivateProfileString(section, key, null, buffer, SIZE, Path);
        int er = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if (er > 0)
            throw new Exception($"GetPrivateProfileString error {er}. " +
                $"See System Error Codes (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes) for detales");

        //Вернуть полученное значение
        return buffer.Length == 0 ? null : buffer.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// WinAPI - Копирует строку в определенную секцию инициализационного файла
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="AppName">
    /// Имя секции в которую строка будет скопированна. Если секция не существует, то она создастся. Имя секции регистро-независимо.
    /// Строка может состоять из любых комбинаций букв верхнего и нижнего регистра  
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="KeyName">
    /// Имя ключа которое будет ассоциировано со строкой. Если ключь не содержится в секции, то он создастся. 
    /// Если данный параметр null - то вся секция включая всё в секции - удаляется
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="Str">
    /// "null-termonated" строка (завершается на '/0') для записи в файл. Если параметр null - Если параметр null, то параметр переданный в качестве ключа KeyName - будет удален  
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="FileName">
    /// Имя инициализационного файла. Строка будет хаписана с исспользованием Unicode, если файл был создан с исспользованием Unicode символов. 
    /// Иначе будет исспользована ANSI кодировка
    /// </param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private extern static int WritePrivateProfileString(String AppName, String KeyName, String Str, String FileName);
    /// <summary>
    /// Удобная обертка для WinAPI WritePrivateProfileString
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="section">Секция</param>
    /// <param name="key">Ключ</param>
    /// <param name="value">Значение</param>
    private void WriteParam(string section, string key, string value)
    {
        //Записать значение в INI-файл
        WritePrivateProfileString(section, key, value, Path);
        int er = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if (er > 0)
            throw new Exception($"WritePrivateProfileString error {er}." +
                $". See System Error Codes (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes) for detales");
    }
    #endregion
```

В конструкторе класса, если файл не существует - создаю его следующим образом:

```
Path = path;
   if (!File.Exists(path))
   {
       var file = File.Create(path);
       file.Close();
   }
```

Однако по чему то при попытке прочесть или записать в файл - получаю ошибку ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND не смотря на то что файл присутствуют на диске. В чем может быть дело ?

А вот если читаю файлик который был создан не моей программой (скопировал тестовый файл) - то тогда файл читается нормально.

Comment: дело может быть в том, что вы передаете сюда один путь `if (!File.Exists(path))`, а в реальности файл лежит по другому пути

Comment: @tym32167 Первой же строкой я присваиваю переменное Path значение path так что путь один и тотже

Comment: И какое конкретно значение у этой переменной?

Comment: @tym32167 C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyTestConfig.ini

Comment: слеши экранированы само собой

Comment: У меня подозрение что проблема в кодировке. файл создается в UTF8 а файлик который я скопировал из проги другой - в кодировке SBCSCodePageEncoding

Comment: @tym32167 Да судя по всему (информация с mdsn - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/43eb2827-e840-414d-b8fa-eb560a53c46f/using-getprivateprofilestring-with-utf8?forum=vclanguage) проблема в кодировке. Подскажите как указать кодировку в файле при его создании ?

Comment: Вы просто указываете кодировку когда пишете в файл. При создании файл пустой создается, а в пустом файле нет текста, если его туда не записать.

Comment: Есть ли у Вас еще какие нибудь догадки ? попробуйте создать у себя на компьютере подобную конструкцию получится ли у Вас записать и прочесть файл ?

Comment: ну вы весь ваш код не показали, но я взял [вот отсюда](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1966/An-INI-file-handling-class-using-C) и всё без проблем [работает](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IklWP.png), пишет и читает в кодировке UTF-8.

Comment: @tym32167 - я выложил тот отрезок кода который с файлами работает. посмотрю то что скинули может поможет.

Comment: разобрался оказывается ошибка кидается если файл пустой. Если в нем есть хоть одна запись - то ошибка не выкидывается.

Comment: Вернее так:
ошибка кидается если в нет нет требуемой секции. Если секция присутствует то все в порядке.

Comment: А в моем примере просто пустое значение возвращает

Comment: @tym32167 Подключите возврат ошибок из C как у меня выше. тогда получится тоже самоечто и у меня

Comment: Во  та же ситуация (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34437470/how-to-know-why-getprivateprofileint-string-fail) видимо данные методы не кто почти не использует уже...

Comment: А может ну его, этот устаревший формат ini? Переходите на xml или json. Сериализация - наше всё!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я только за) но я пишу дополнение к проге которая как раз ini использует, так что не от меня зависит это

Answer (score 1):

В коде нет проверки возвращаемого значения для функций WritePrivateProfileString и GetPrivateProfileString. Вы, похоже, предполагаете, что эти функции сбрасывают код последней ошибки в 0, но это не так.

```
if(WritePrivateProfileString(section, key, value, Path) == 0)
{
    int er = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    if (er > 0) throw new Exception("...");
}
```